# Horizontal nav layout with Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav, bootstrap-5

I am having difficulty to get Bootstrap to display my nav options horizontally (i.e. similar to examples shown in the Bootstrap docs at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#nav)

Here is the minimal code in Codepen for my page :
https://codepen.io/6a0a49af-a3f9-4e78-8ccf-91d8d1b1f102/pen/WNGPQQj

Just to be clear: In my Codepen example, `Home Features Pricing` should appear horizontally, not vertically.

I ***think*** the problem might be to do with my use of `flex-column` in `<body>`. But I cannot remove that without breaking other items in my design (for example the sticky footer - using flex for a sticky footer is much cleaner than the hacky alternative of setting fixed height etc. etc.).

So I'm a bit stuck really !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem is the navbar is missing the `navbar-expand` class..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand bg-light">
  ...
</nav>
```

https://codeply.com/p/WSBVjlDiy6

The Bootstrap navbar is mobile-first, so by default it's collapsed. As shown in the docs...

> "Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with
> .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl|-xxl} for responsive collapsing and
> color scheme classes."